# Get facebook friends picture of bigger size using invitable_friends/taggable_friends API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am working on application which shows users friends list based on facebook connections. I am using invitable_friends/taggable_friends API. The picture returns by this API is 50*50 which is very tiny. Is there any way to get picture of different size?

```
{
      "id": "HTdVs5yVQ16UYBLiKTdYWqKCnJYVHv3TSlNpgABGI5Rs1L_acCxQwEaCYJqYo93rlmeHNL8ezL-EANEDn8tmCgtG_8U7qnEVLQPkOYtYGG1Kp7",
      "name": "Dilip Kumar",
      "picture": {
        "data": {
          "is_silhouette": false,
          "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c8.0.50.50/p50x50/13781923_1188731181146913_2378017407833918_8.jpg?oh=30f5e99602d65b8087efec12becd8a34&oe=585E5E66"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: may i ask what for? are you actually using invitable_friends to invite users to a game with canvas implementation?

Comment: Yes. Mainly to invites friends (as per facebook friends list) to participate in discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the fields and use a specific minimum size like this:

```
/me/invitable_friends?fields=name,picture.width(500).height(500)
```

I just tested it in the API Explorer, works fine.